# Is there already a Lego Mindstorms NXT simulation in Gazebo?

Tags: ros, gazebo, nxt, lego

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [NXT wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/NXT) says: "... and in the future we hope to add simulation capabilities in gazebo, our 3D simulator." Did anybody already do any work in that direction? What would still have to be done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10104/is-there-already-a-lego-mindstorms-nxt-simulation-in-gazebo?/) by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11816 on 2011-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Work has not begun on NXT in gazebo. What needs to be done is port the NXT meshes to a format readable by Gazebo (Collada or STL are the best), and then write plugins for the various actuators and sensors.

If you want to start work on this, just ask for more help and we can provide you with some more guidance.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.ros.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 431 on 2011-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1